# No memsql.sock file in /var/lib/memsql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, singlestore

The error mentioned here: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/tshoot/2002/ I was getting using Ubuntu 14.04.2. The MySQL client and the latest MemSQL advised to point the 'my.cnf' config to the 'memsql.sock' file located in '/var/lib/memsql', however there is no such file.

After much searching and troubleshooting, there are similar errors but without the proper file they're irrelevant in as much that without the 'memsql.sock' file there can be no connection. I'm considering using MemSQL in production soon.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reasons why you might observe this behavior.

1. First of all, note that the documentation suggests that the file is under `/var/lib/memsql/data`, while based on your question you might be looking for it under `/var/lib/memsql`.
2. It could also be that your MemSQL is not installed in `/var/lib/memsql`, but in some other place. In this case the `memsql.sock` file will be in the `data` subdirectory of the directory where your MemSQL is installed.
3. Finally, it could be that your `memsql.cnf` is missing the `socket` argument. You need to configure both the client and the server to use the same socket. The documentation page you pointed to suggests to change `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` -- that's the client config. Your server config is in the `memsql.cnf` file, which is most likely in `/var/lib/memsql/memsql.cnf`. Make sure it has the following line:

```sh
socket              = memsql.sock
```

Then as you restart MemSQL, it will create the `memsql.sock` file.

If none of this works, you can also just connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, in which case the `memsql.sock` file will not be used.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to respond. Even though I mentioned the /var/lib/memsql directory I actually meant, and looked for, memsql.sock in every directory AFTER the MemSQL install including the one mentioned in the doc, and where the config points to, /var/lib/memsql/data/ and after having MemSQL Op up and running. I tried re-installing twice and restoring from a snapshot since I'm using VMWare but to no avail. I tried various connect settings including localhost, 127.0.0.1 to no avail either and the settings you mentioned in memsql.cnf were correct. I'll keep trying tomorrow. Thx.

Comment: I tried installing a fresh copy again and experienced the same issue. I've linked to some screenshots that show the error, the directory with the missing file, the memsql.cnf file with correct settings and different connection attempts.: http://j.mp/1HEtsDM http://j.mp/1HEtwTR http://j.mp/1HEtxqZ http://j.mp/1cdZ0SE http://j.mp/1cdZ19p Thx.

Comment: I tried on a fresh install of Ubuntu Vivid with all updates and same problem; the install doesn't create any 'memsql.sock' file AND there is not a 'memsql.sock' file anywhere in any directory (before or after install) AND there is no mention of 'memsql.sock' in 'install.sh' (which you would think would make sense given that if it is installed during install it would at least create one). I would try a different SQL client but it wouldn't make a difference since it wouldn't help create said file.

Comment: Note that when you try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` it doesn't complain about the sccket file, but rather cannot connect for some other reason. I would suggest to try two things: (1) confirm that MemSQL is actually up and running by executing `ps ax | grep memsqld` (2) confirm that MemSQL is running on port 3306 (`port` variable in memsql.cnf, if it is not set, it defaults to 3306), and that the client config doesn't overwrite the port anywhere (I see on your screenshot it is 3306, just want to doublecheck it is not overwritten withing the same file).

Comment: Also, the `memsql.sock` file is not created during the installation, it is created when MemSQL launches.

Comment: Thanks for the response again. Every time I tried to connect MemSQL Ops is/was up and running. I confirmed all of the settings and that everything was working. If the memsql.sock file is created when MemSQL launches then wouldn't it have been created already if MemSQL Ops is working and I'm able to connect to it on port 9000 via HTTP?

Comment: Note that MemSQL ops and MemSQL server are two different things. MemSQL ops is a cluster management tool from which you launch MemSQL instances. Make sure you started at least one aggregator and at least one leaf

Comment: I got word out to help-memsql[at]memsql.com and they made some suggestions. It seems that all is working with MySQL server installed but without MySQL server installed I get the same errors. I asked if having it installed is a pre-req and will post here as soon as I hear something. Thanks again for your reply(ies).

Comment: "To answer your question - MySQL Server is not required to run MemSQL. There is almost certainly something else in your environment that is causing this confusion. If you've specified both the host (127.0.0.1) and port (3306), you do not need to use the socket file. My guess is that in your environment, MemSQL is running on port 3307 (we will automatically start it on port 3307 if there is something else, like MySQL, occupying port 3306)." I'll try the fix suggested and report back.

Comment: The command: "mysql -u root -P 3307 --prompt="memsql> "" yields: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" I'm going to try and adjust the settings according to the doc mentioned in my first post and report back.

Comment: I tried adjusting the settings accordingly with no luck. I'm going to try a different Linux distro and also try it on my Mac and see what happens. This will take a little time but I'll try and reply asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `mysql` client without `-h 127.0.0.1` it will try to connect to the socket, which by default is set to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. This is typically set in `/etc/mysqld/my.cnf` or wherever your `my.conf` file is. If you change your `$HOME/.my.cnf` file to have

`[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/memsql/data/memsql.sock`

this should work. Note, this is a behavior of the `mysql` client not MemSQL.